Blank page on localhost\phpinfo.php
I'm new to Linux. So I want to install Apache + MySQL + phpmyadmin.

I install Apache2 and it works fine (localhost) and shows the webpage.

When I install PHP using the command sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php, it installs fine but I can not see anything when visiting localhost/phpinfo.php

I enable the PHP module and restart Apache

I prioritize PHP under dir.conf and edit the phpinfo.php page


I also purged all the files and reinstalled it including doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. I even asked ChatGPT and they gave me the same answers.
What I'm missing?

An actual question would be nice. What is missing is not a question that can be answered.

Does the file phpinfo.php exist and does it contain the following code <?php phpinfo();
